# How to move point with shape's changing rotation and position

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, computational-geometry, shapes

I have a web app,  where I am drawing a triangle and also drawing points on top of it to show the vertices that it has. (fig 1 at 0 radians)

[image]

The circle and triangle rotate fine, its just the blue point that I cant seem to move appropriately. When I rotate the triangle (along with circle), the X and Y does not translate to either corners of the triangle besides the red dot. (fig 2 at .75 radians) [image]

The shape as a whole is drawn with the following vertices for display points.

```
this.transform = ctx.getTransform();
this.boundPoints[0] = { //red point
        x: (this.transform.a + this.x)+(this.radius)* Math.cos(this.rotation),
        y: (this.transform.d + this.y)+(this.radius)* Math.sin(this.rotation)
}

this.boundPoints[1] = { //blue point
        x:  (this.transform.a + this.x)+(this.radius+ this.range)* Math.cos(this.rotation), 
        y:  (this.transform.d + this.y)+(this.radius)* Math.sin(this.rotation)
    }
```

What I want to have happen, is this [image]

Where that point keeps its position relative to the triangle regardless of its position and rotation in the canvas. Without rotating, I can keep it there with its Y being

`y: (this.transform.d + this.y+this.range)`

but now I can't rotate or move the shape without the dot losing its placement. (Note: this.rotation is angle in radians)

Answer (score 1):

My way of keeping track of all point of any shape is to create any array in my class that stores those values separate from the actual points that you are drawing to. I use those stored point mainly for collision detection with an odd shape that has been transformed/rotated/scaled.

Without your code it's hard to see how I would implement this technique but here's an example of a rotating triangle that you can scale and transform and the points are always tracked. This example also includes a commented out piece of code showing how to use the centroid to rotate from the center is needed.

`this.position` is the trasnlate
`this.size` is scale
`this.r` is rotate

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;

let ptACopy, ptBCopy, ptCCopy;
class Triangle {
  constructor(ptA, ptB, ptC) {
    this.type = "tri";
    this.ptA = ptACopy = ptA;
    this.ptB = ptBCopy = ptB;
    this.ptC = ptCCopy = ptC;
    this.position = { x: 100, y: 100 }; //use this to position
    this.size = { x: 2, y: 1 };
    this.centroid = {
      ox: (this.ptA.x + this.ptB.x + this.ptC.x) / 3,
      oy: (this.ptA.y + this.ptB.y + this.ptC.y) / 3
    };
    this.c = "red";
    this.a = 0;
    this.r = this.a * (Math.PI / 180);
    this.points = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      this.points.push({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    }
  }
  draw() {
    //updates the points to counter the translating of the canvas to the centroid
   //this is used to rotate from center if wanted
    /*this.ptA = {
      x: ptACopy.x - this.centroid.ox,
      y: ptACopy.y - this.centroid.oy
    };
    this.ptB = {
      x: ptBCopy.x - this.centroid.ox,
      y: ptBCopy.y - this.centroid.oy
    };
    this.ptC = {
      x: ptCCopy.x - this.centroid.ox,
      y: ptCCopy.y - this.centroid.oy
    };*/ 

    let cos = Math.cos(this.r);
    let sin = Math.sin(this.r);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.c;
    ctx.setTransform(cos * this.size.x, sin * this.size.x, -sin * this.size.y, cos * this.size.y, this.position.x, this.position.y);
    ctx.moveTo(this.ptA.x, this.ptA.y);
    ctx.lineTo(this.ptB.x, this.ptB.y);
    ctx.lineTo(this.ptC.x, this.ptC.y);
    ctx.lineTo(this.ptA.x, this.ptA.y);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
  }
  updateCorners() {
    this.a += 0.1;
    this.r = this.a * (Math.PI / 180);
    let cos = Math.cos(this.r);
    let sin = Math.sin(this.r);
    this.points[0].x =
      this.ptA.x * this.size.x * cos -
      this.ptA.y * this.size.y * sin +
      this.position.x;
    this.points[0].y =
      this.ptA.x * this.size.x * sin +
      this.ptA.y * this.size.y * cos +
      this.position.y;
    this.points[1].x =
      this.ptB.x * this.size.x * cos -
      this.ptB.y * this.size.y * sin +
      this.position.x;
    this.points[1].y =
      this.ptB.x * this.size.x * sin +
      this.ptB.y * this.size.y * cos +
      this.position.y;
    this.points[2].x =
      this.ptC.x * this.size.x * cos -
      this.ptC.y * this.size.y * sin +
      this.position.x;
    this.points[2].y =
      this.ptC.x * this.size.x * sin +
      this.ptC.y * this.size.y * cos +
      this.position.y;
  }
  drawPoints() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    this.points.map((x) => {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x.x, x.y, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fill();
    });
  }
}
let triangle = new Triangle(
  { x: 10, y: 20 },
  { x: 50, y: 60 },
  { x: 30, y: 100 }
);

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  triangle.draw();
  triangle.updateCorners();
  triangle.drawPoints();

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

To clarify some things in the code:
The purpose of using the following code is to ensure the shape is accurately drawn when translating it.

```
this.ptA = {
          x: ptACopy.x - this.centroid.ox,
          y: ptACopy.y - this.centroid.oy
        };
```

If is were to not make a copy of the points and try to do

```
this.ptA = {
          x: ptA.x - this.centroid.ox,
          y: ptA.y - this.centroid.oy
        };
```

then I would just get undefined because I'm trying to use ptA to calculate ptA.

Also when creating the triangle if I wanted ptA to be at (0,0) then I could set it there and then use the above function to offset the triangle for rotation purposes. example using that to have it rotate around ptA with a 20px radius:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;

let ptACopy, ptBCopy, ptCCopy;
class Triangle {
  constructor(ptA, ptB, ptC) {
    this.type = "tri";
    this.ptA = ptACopy = ptA;
    this.ptB = ptBCopy = ptB;
    this.ptC = ptCCopy = ptC;
    this.position = { x: 100, y: 100 }; //use this to position
    this.size = { x: 1, y: 1 };
    this.centroid = {
      ox: (this.ptA.x + this.ptB.x + this.ptC.x) / 3,
      oy: (this.ptA.y + this.ptB.y + this.ptC.y) / 3
    };
    this.c = "red";
    this.a = 0;
    this.r = this.a * (Math.PI / 180);
    this.points = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      this.points.push({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    }
  }
  draw() {
    //updates the points to counter the translating of the canvas to the centroid
    this.ptA = {
      x: ptACopy.x + 20,
      y: ptACopy.y + 20
    };
    this.ptB = {
      x: ptBCopy.x + 20,
      y: ptBCopy.y + 20
    };
    this.ptC = {
      x: ptCCopy.x + 20,
      y: ptCCopy.y + 20
    };
    let cos = Math.cos(this.r);
    let sin = Math.sin(this.r);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.c;
    ctx.setTransform(cos * this.size.x, sin * this.size.x, -sin * this.size.y, cos * this.size.y, this.position.x, this.position.y);
    ctx.moveTo(this.ptA.x, this.ptA.y);
    ctx.lineTo(this.ptB.x, this.ptB.y);
    ctx.lineTo(this.ptC.x, this.ptC.y);
    ctx.lineTo(this.ptA.x, this.ptA.y);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.restore();
  }
  updateCorners() {
    this.a += 0.5;
    this.r = this.a * (Math.PI / 180);
    let cos = Math.cos(this.r);
    let sin = Math.sin(this.r);
    this.points[0].x =
      this.ptA.x * this.size.x * cos -
      this.ptA.y * this.size.y * sin +
      this.position.x;
    this.points[0].y =
      this.ptA.x * this.size.x * sin +
      this.ptA.y * this.size.y * cos +
      this.position.y;
    this.points[1].x =
      this.ptB.x * this.size.x * cos -
      this.ptB.y * this.size.y * sin +
      this.position.x;
    this.points[1].y =
      this.ptB.x * this.size.x * sin +
      this.ptB.y * this.size.y * cos +
      this.position.y;
    this.points[2].x =
      this.ptC.x * this.size.x * cos -
      this.ptC.y * this.size.y * sin +
      this.position.x;
    this.points[2].y =
      this.ptC.x * this.size.x * sin +
      this.ptC.y * this.size.y * cos +
      this.position.y;
  }
  drawPoints() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    this.points.map((x) => {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x.x, x.y, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fill();
    });
  }
}
let triangle = new Triangle(
  { x: 0, y: 0 },
  { x: 50, y: 60 },
  { x: 30, y: 100 }
);

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  triangle.draw();
  triangle.updateCorners();
  triangle.drawPoints();

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

I gave the canvas a background for better visualization.

***UPDATE:***

I am adding an example using `getTransform()` which returns the transformation matrix.

We can then use those values to calculate each point by passing them to a function. This shortens the code slightly inside the class and makes things look cleaner IMO.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 400;

let t;

class Rect {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.scale = {x: 1, y: 1}
    this.cx = this.x + this.w / 2;
    this.cy = this.y + this.h / 2;
    this.color = "red";
    this.angle = 0;
    this.rotation = (this.angle * Math.PI) / 180;
    this.pts = []
  }
  draw() {
    this.angle += 0.5;
    this.rotation = (this.angle * Math.PI) / 180;
    const cos = Math.cos(this.rotation)
    const sin = Math.sin(this.rotation)
    ctx.save();
    ctx.setTransform(cos * this.scale.x, sin * this.scale.x, -sin * this.scale.y, cos * this.scale.y, this.x, this.y);
    t = ctx.getTransform();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(-this.w / 2, -this.h / 2, this.w, this.h);
    ctx.restore();
  }
  drawVertices() {
    for (let i=0; i < this.pts.length; i++) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
      ctx.arc(this.pts[i].x, this.pts[i].y, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
    }
  }
  updateVertices() {   
    this.pts[0] = calcVertices(t['a'], t['b'], t['c'], t['d'], t['e'], t['f'], 0, 0, this.cx, this.cy)//top left width and height are passed as 0.
    this.pts[1] = calcVertices(t['a'], t['b'], t['c'], t['d'], t['e'], t['f'], this.w, 0, this.cx, this.cy) //top right only passes width. Height is 0.
    this.pts[2] = calcVertices(t['a'], t['b'], t['c'], t['d'], t['e'], t['f'], this.w, this.h, this.cx, this.cy) //bottom right passes both wodth and height.
    this.pts[3] = calcVertices(t['a'], t['b'], t['c'], t['d'], t['e'], t['f'], 0, this.h, this.cx, this.cy)//bottom left only passes height. Width is 0.
   }
}

let rect1 = new Rect(100, 100, 50, 75);
let rect2 = new Rect(250, 150, 100, 25);

function calcVertices(a, b, c, d, e, f, w, h, cx, cy) {
  let x, y;
  x = (e + w - cx) * a + (f + h - cy) * c + (e);
  y = (e + w - cx) * b + (f + h - cy) * d + (f);
  
  return {x: x, y: y}
}

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  rect1.draw();
  rect1.updateVertices();
  rect1.drawVertices();
  rect2.draw();
  rect2.updateVertices();
  rect2.drawVertices();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yeah its a bit harder for me to post all of the code. Its spread across subclasses for shapes. So the images I have are 3 different classes being used. One for the circle, a triangle, and a simple dot class for each point. But they all extend from a Sprite class which handles the data initially. We have the same approach though when constructing the triangle. Your updatecorners function seems more appropriate for updating each point. My boundPoints array would be the points list you have. I will try to integrate your solution, thanks!

Comment: I hope is helps. I added some more info and another snippet that may clear up some things.

Comment: I got the points to draw and update correctly. Your updateCorners function handles sin and cos for each side appropriately. Thanks!

Comment: Glad its working for you. I did add an example using `getTransform` which you may also be interested in using. I think for my code I was able to clean things up a bit and make it easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer with complex numbers for convenience, but every complex expression can be rewritten with reals only.

You did not specify the rotation center (presumably the origin) and for generality I will assume the point `c`. To rotate any point `p` around this center, we apply the equation

```
p' = r.(p - c) + c
```

where `r = cos Θ + i sin Θ` implements a rotation by angle `Θ`.

Now to rotate any shape, assuming that the shape has a reference point (say its center or some other remarkable point such as a corner), you need to apply the rotation to this reference point, and assign the angle `Θ` to the shape (if the shape already had an angle `τ` assigned to it, the new angle is `τ + Θ`.)

If you also want to rescale the shape, use `r = s (cos Θ + i sin Θ)` where `s` is the desired scaling factor and apply this transformation to the reference point. Also apply the factor s to all dimension parameters of the shapes (or `t . s` is the parameters already had a factor `t` applied.)